# Search raw text from url, using keyword from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, search

Me and my buddy Xylophone have been at this for hours and cant figure this out, any help would be appreciated. I'm basically trying to read all the text from that URL and search for a keyword.

```
if (comboBoxEdit1.Text == "Hello")
{
    label2.Text = "Current Status: Searching...";
    this.dataGridView3.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
    this.dataGridView3.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(mousewheel);
    dataGridView3.Rows.Clear();
    string line;
    int row = 0;
    List<String> LinesFound = new List<string>();
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader("https://pastebin.com/raw/fWxKdRjN");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(textEdit1.Text))
        {
            string[] Columns = line.Split(':');
            dataGridView3.Rows.Add(line);
            for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridView3[i, row].Value = Columns[i];
            }
            row++;
            label2.Text = "Current Status: " + dataGridView3.Rows.Count + "  Matche(s) Found";
        }
        else if (dataGridView3.RowCount == 0)
        {
            label2.Text = "Current Status: No Matche(s) Found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also to add, it's only reading the first line of raw text.

Comment: I have answered you and you code has multiple issues, that lead to multiple questions. If you can not use my answer, I think you need to make you question more focused other wise I gone end up writing explicit solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all wrong, if you want to read and pars the html content of the web page, you need to fetch the page using httpClient, or better take look at this library https://html-agility-pack.net/

Answer (score 0):

We can `use regular expression` to check if 'raw' exist in the URL.
`Regex.Matches()` function will return an array with all occurrence of the match.
We can then use count property to find the no of occurence.

**Regular expression to match raw in a url:*`(raw)`***

> Below is the working code snippet:

```
 public static void Main()
   {
       string pattern = @"(raw)";
       Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
       string url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/fWxKdRjN";
       if (rgx.Matches(url).Count>0){
          Console.WriteLine(Current Status: " + rgx.Matches(url).Count + "  Matche(s) Found");
         }  
       else {
          Console.WriteLine("Current Status: No Matche(s) Found");
        }
   }
```